# How do I check the maxlength in a component template

Tags: templating, 2009

How can I find the maxlength of the number of items?

TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex == 0"

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `CollectionLength` function:

```
@@CollectionLength("Component.Fields.multiValuedField")@@
```

Refer to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052182/how-to-get-the-maximum-index-count-for-templaterepeatindex-in-dwt

Comment: I got the error Variable 'CollectionLength' has not been declared. How to declare it?

Comment: What version are you on? What is the exact code you are using?

Comment: Tridion 2009 SP1

Comment: I'm afraid it was added in the later version. You will probably have to implement it yourself

Comment: Check this extension, might do the trick for you: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/dreamweavercia.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why not write a C# TBB to check the number of Items, In case you cannot use any external tools.
Example:

```
Item compItem = package.GetByType(ContentType.Component);
XmlDocument Links = new XmlDocument();
Links.LoadXml(compItem.Content.OuterXml);
XmlNodeList OuterImageCount = Links.GetElementsByTagName("OuterImage");
string Count = (OuterImageCount.Count).ToString();
package.PushItem("ItemsCount", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, Count));
```

And in DWT you can read the `ItemsCount` item pushed to Package as:

Reading the value inside condition as:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex == ItemsCount" -->
```

And in case you want to use the value any where else in DWT, use: `@@ItemsCount@@`

Where `OuterImage` is the repeating element as

```
<OuterImage>
<LinkUrl>http://www.google.co.in</LinkUrl> 
<Image>xlink:title="primary-icon-7" xlink:href="tcm:218-12168"></Image>
</OuterImage>

<OuterImage>
<LinkUrl>http://www.google.co.in</LinkUrl> 
<Image>xlink:title="primary-icon-8" xlink:href="tcm:218-12169"></Image>
</OuterImage>
....
....
<OuterImage>
<LinkUrl>http://www.google.co.in</LinkUrl> 
<Image>xlink:title="primary-icon-9" xlink:href="tcm:218-12170"></Image>
</OuterImage>
```